# Unexpected Output When Appending Objects to an Array

Tags: python, object

In a program I am writing, I'm trying to append an object to a list, make a small change to that object, and then append the second version of the object to that list.  The code below is not the one in which I encountered this error originally, but it shows the same problem.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

a = A()
b = []
for i in range(10):
    b.append(a)
    a.val += 1

for a in b:
    print(a)
```

This is the expected output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

This is the actual output:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: You need to call `A()` once for each object, otherwise it is all the same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a new value to the `same object` on each iteration of the `for` loop. You need to create a `new object each time` and give it a value like this:

```
class A(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.val = 0

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.val)

b = []
for i in range(10):
    b.append(A())
    b[i].val = i;


for a in b:
    print(a)
```

which outputs

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are appending the same object, every time in the list, but just changing the value of "val". So when the for loop ends. The object has val = 10, as you appended the same object 10 times, all items in the list are the value 10. Try appending diffents objects of the same class callign A() every time :)